# Alamofire upload failing with file over 1MB

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am struggling with an issue using Alamofire in Swift 5 when uploading an audio file to a server.
If the filesize is 1MB or less, everything is fine but as soon as the file is greater than 1MB, it seems to timeout but I can't figure out if the issue is Alamofire or on the server side.
When the upload fails, I get the following errors in the console;

```
2021-09-13 10:36:26.966452-0500 App Name[32446:2616254] Task <EFF172FB-4FD0-4857-8727-84D91F6C06A9>.<1> HTTP load failed, 1048956/463 bytes (error code: -1017 [4:-1])
2021-09-13 10:36:26.970745-0500 App Name[32446:2617311] Task <EFF172FB-4FD0-4857-8727-84D91F6C06A9>.<1> finished with error [-1017] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000011fa940 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x600003c7f390 [0x7fff8004b340]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bbd82eb8f90000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <EFF172FB-4FD0-4857-8727-84D91F6C06A9>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalUploadTask <EFF172FB-4FD0-4857-8727-84D91F6C06A9>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://<server and endpoint>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://<server and endpoint>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
```

I've tried debugging but can't figure it out and am looking for any suggestions. Here is the code;

```
fileprivate func UploadAudio(_ todaysDate: String) -> DataRequest {
        return AF.upload(multipartFormData: { [self] multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(finalFilename, withName: "audio", fileName: "final.wav", mimeType: "audio/x-wav")
        },to: Constants.getUrl()+"<api endpoint>").debugLog().authenticate(username: defaults.string(forKey: "username")!, password: defaults.string(forKey: "password")!)
        .uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
            self.progressView!.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("Here is audio submission form")
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")
            print("Error: \(String(describing: response.error))")

            if(self.alertView != nil)
            {
                self.alertView.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
            if let audioLocation = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Location"] as? String {
                _ = self.StartTranscription(audioLocation)
            }
            else
            {
                self.showAlert(title: "Alert", message: "Couldn't get the location URL")
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, if the audio file is less than 1MB, it uploads fine, I get a valid JSON response and things are great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error on the server?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez It's not my server so I can't get any errors there that aren't returned to the response. I spoke with the server admins and they say there aren't any limitations on that endpoint that should be affecting this.

Comment: @RyanH - Even though they say they have no limitations did they check for any errors for your request?   I have run into an issue similar before and once they checked the server logs we found it was an issue on their end.

Comment: @MwcsMac I just did a test by changing the endpoint to another server using a different API and I am also getting an error sending there if the file is over 1MB so it seems to be an issue with my Alamofire code somehow.
I tried with a PCM file and with an m4a and got same. I checked out PHP logs on our server and there were no errors. I know 100% that our server supports up to 150MB uploads using that API and is used frequently from an upload page.

Comment: Further to my previous comment. I did make a mistake. It failed on our server due to a different error unrelated to the API. I have been able to upload files greater than 1MB there so it looks like it may in fact be an issue on the server....

Comment: So after waiting for a response from the server ops, all I got back was they see the request for the file under 1MB but they don't see anything for the file over 1MB. Not much help.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with Alamofire. We had to switch to URL Session and then we had no issues at all.
This doesn't explain what the issue actually was but that it had something to do with Alamofire.
The code posted in the OP wouldn't work but the following code works as expected;

```
        if(self.progressView != nil)
        {
            self.progressView.progress  = Float(Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend))
        }
    }
    
    var urlSession = URLSession.shared
    
    func sendPostRequest(
        to url: URL,
        filePath: String,
        then handler: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        var body:Data? = nil
        body = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        var request = URLRequest(
            url: url,
            cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        )
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let task = urlSession.uploadTask(
            with: request,
            from: body,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                // Validate response and call handler
                
            }
        )
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

I don't know if this will help anyone out or not but wanted to post how it was fixed in case someone else runs into the same issue.